# Japanese Maple in Full Sun in Dallas Texas

Tags: trees, japanese-maple

I live in Plano, texas. I have a house facing east. I am thinking of planting Japanese Maple tree in my backyard. Wondering if Japanese maple can withstand texas heat, considering it's not going to be under a shade. But I do have fence at back about 7ft, and the tree will in the corner of NW direction, as shown in the image). But almost 100 % of the tree will get full sun from 11ish to 3ish.

Are there other varieties of Japanes Maple that could withstand sun better than others. Please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the sun exposure you describe is at the worst  possible time of day for a japanese Acer. These are really understory trees, meaning they will grow best being given dappled shade between the hours of 11-3 pm, so a taller tree nearby (but not too close) that provides those conditions is ideal.

There is information here http://www.metromaples.com/growing-japanese-maples in regard to sun sensitivity of  different varieties - the green leaved ones aren't quite as sensitive, but even those will not appreciate that much sun during high summer.